# Wrong Setting with my Wordpress Themes

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I just installed **wordpress** in **softclaus**. After installing, I visit **wp-admin** and sign in. I want to change the theme of my wordpress site. I click the **Appreance Themes** and there is no option to **add new theme**. It only has a **Twenty Sixteen theme**. Is there a setting I must change first? or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be not possible for you to install a theme because of a line in your wp-config.php.

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);
```

Can you check if you can install plugins ? Or check this file at your wordpress root using ftp ?

The Twenty Sixteen theme is the default theme of wordpress.